I can't select the ADT in the Asset Categories Navigation portlet configuration (Liferay 7.4)
I inform you that the version of Liferay I am working on is: liferay-ce-portal-7.4.3.112-ga112.
The problem is that I cannot select the ADT template because it is not shown in the Asset Categories Navigation Portlet configuration dropdown.
Below, the process that has been carried out will be indicated through screenshots.
1º) The ADT "adt_filtro_empleos" has been created without problem.

2º) Display of the Asset Categories Navigation Portlet on the page.

3º) The Asset Categories Portlet configuration option is selected.

4º) The ADT "adt_filtro_empleos" cannot be selected because it is not shown in the dropdown.


Why can't the ADT "adt_filtro_empleos" be selected?
Am I doing something wrong?
Is it a bug?

Regards.

I found the error. I had created a content publisher template instead of a category navigation template.

Regards.
